# In the Office 365 Sharepoint Document Library. Can you automate folder approval, but NOT file approval?

Tags: directory, office365, power-automate

So I need to automate the approval for all folders created but NOT the files created in the doc library. However i see NO options for folders only for the files. Is this possible or am i wasting my time and need to move on?  I have literally went through all of power automate and the share point setting site i cant find anything. I cant use coding outside of VBA due to company restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'Get files (properties only)' SharePoint flow, then add a condition on the 'Is Folder' properties, and when True, set your desired approval.

[image: Power Automate Example]

[image: Root]

Comment: Thank you I will try it in the morning! Much appreciated:-)